# How would I seed the PCG RNG with a chosen, set seed?

Tags: c++, random-seed

For testing purposes I need to seed [PCG](https://www.pcg-random.org/)'s C++ implementation (the 64 bit output one) with a set value. When I look at the examples I only see it seeding using entropy.

I've used

```
pcg64 rng(42);
```

and it's worked, rng() generating the same numbers every time, but PCG64 uses a 256-bit seed and this way seems to generate the same numbers for each value above the 64 bit integer limit.

What's the best way to seed it with known values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I read [source code](https://www.pcg-random.org/), `pcg64` is an instantination of `engine` template class which accepts `pcg128_t` seed value in constructor. So it is only 128 bit value, not 256 bit.

There are two ways how you can pass 128 bit seed to constructor. First is if you already have pre-defined two 64-bit values, then you can use `PCG_128BIT_CONSTANT(hi, lo)` macro for building 128 bit value, and write code:

```cpp
pcg64 rng{PCG_128BIT_CONSTANT(0xC7C8709C9626D159ULL, 0x675BB824D76E9146ULL)};
```

Second way is by using [std::mt19937_64](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) random generator and maybe [std::random_device](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) (for initializing random generator):

```cpp
#include <random>
....
std::mt19937_64 seed{0xC7C8709C9626D159ULL};
// or
// std::mt19937_64 seed{std::random_device()};
pcg64 rng{PCG_128BIT_CONSTANT(seed(), seed())};
```

You can also use [std::seed_seq](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq) for same purpose as `std::mt19937_64` was used above:

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
....
std::seed_seq seed{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::array<uint32_t, 4> seeds{};
seed.generate(seeds.begin(), seeds.end());
pcg64 rng{PCG_128BIT_CONSTANT(((uint64_t(seeds[0]) << 32) | seeds[1]),
    ((uint64_t(seeds[2]) << 32) | seeds[3]))};
```